# Using different ADC channels

Tags: arduino-uno

How could the same code be used with different ADC channels?

```cpp
const byte adcPin = 0;  // A0

const int MAX_RESULTS = 100;

volatile int resultsV [MAX_RESULTS];
volatile int resultsI [MAX_RESULTS];

volatile int resultNumber;

void setup ()
{
  Serial.begin (115200);
  Serial.println ();

  // reset Timer 1
  TCCR1A = 0;
  TCCR1B = 0;
  TCNT1 = 0;
  TCCR1B = bit (CS11) | bit (WGM12);  // CTC, prescaler of 8
  TIMSK1 = bit (OCIE1B);
  OCR1A = 338;
  OCR1B = 338;   // 39 = 20 uS - sampling frequency 50 kHz

  ADCSRA =  bit (ADEN) | bit (ADIE) | bit (ADIF);   // turn ADC on, want interrupt on completion
  ADCSRA |= bit (ADPS2);  // Prescaler of 16
  //  ADCSRA |= (1 << ADPS1) | (1 << ADPS0);    // 8 prescaler for 153.8 KHz
  ADMUX = bit (REFS0) | (adcPin & 7);
  ADCSRB = bit (ADTS0) | bit (ADTS2);  // Timer/Counter1 Compare Match B
  ADCSRA |= bit (ADATE);   // turn on automatic triggering
}

// ADC complete ISR
ISR (ADC_vect)
{
  resultsV[resultNumber++] = ADC;

  //resultsI[resultNumber++] = ADC;

  if (resultNumber == MAX_RESULTS)
  {
    ADCSRA = 0;  // turn off ADC
  }
}

EMPTY_INTERRUPT (TIMER1_COMPB_vect);

void loop () {

  while (resultNumber < MAX_RESULTS)
  { }

  for (int i = 0; i < MAX_RESULTS; i++)
  {
    Serial.print( resultsV);
    Serial.print("   ");
    Serial.print( resultsI);
    Serial.println();
  }
  resultNumber = 0;
  ADCSRA =  bit (ADEN) | bit (ADIE) | bit (ADIF) | bit (ADPS2) | bit (ADATE);
  // turn ADC back on
}
```

Comment: To use a different channel you'd change ADMUX.  See the datasheet to determine what it should be.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you want to read *two* ADC channels
simultaneously. First, you have to understand that you cannot read them
exactly at the same time, as you have a single ADC. What you can do,
however, is read them one after the other: you read the V channel, then
the I channel, then the V channel again, etc. This means you will have
to change the multiplexer setting (the `ADMUX` register) in between the
readings. The most convenient place to do this is within the ADC ISR,
the logic of which becomes:

1. Save the value that has just been read
2. switch the multiplexer to the other channel
3. turn off the ADC if you are done.

Example code (not tested):

```
const byte PIN_V = 0;  // A0
const byte PIN_I = 1;  // A1

// ADC complete ISR.
ISR(ADC_vect)
{
    if (ADMUX & 7 == PIN_V) {
        // We have just read the V channel.
        // Save the value and switch to the I channel.
        resultsV[resultNumber] = ADC;
        ADMUX = bit(REFS0) | PIN_I;
    } else {
        // Otherwise we completed a (V, I) pair, we can increment
        // resultNumber.
        resultsI[resultNumber++] = ADC;
        ADMUX = bit(REFS0) | PIN_V;
    }

    // Turn off the ADC when done.
    if (resultNumber == MAX_RESULTS)
        ADCSRA = 0;
}
```

Note that this example assumes you do the readings in the (V, I) order.
Thus, within `setup()`, you have to initialize the multiplexer for the V
channel, as in

```
ADMUX = bit(REFS0) | PIN_V;
```